# How to draw labels on a screen: MLKit Object Detection

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, android-camerax, google-mlkit

This is an extension of a question I asked before.

I'm using the recent version of MLKit Object Detection (which doesn't require firebase). I'm using a custom model, and CameraX, to detect objects and label them/get info.

Right now, with the code I have, it can detect that objects are present in the area, but:

1. No labels or bounding boxes are showing up;
2. It is not detecting more than one object at a time;
3. Once it detects an object, the app won't "change" (i.e when I move the phone, to try to detect another object, nothing in the display changes.

Here is my code:

````
package com.example.mlkitobjecttest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.Camera;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraX;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.core.impl.PreviewConfig;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Rational;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.mlkit.common.model.LocalModel;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.DetectedObject;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetection;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetector;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private class YourAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        @Override
        @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
        public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {

            Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                InputImage image =
                        InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                // ...
                LocalModel localModel =
                        new LocalModel.Builder()
                                .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_1.0_128_quantized_1_default_1.tflite")
                                // or .setAbsoluteFilePath(absolute file path to tflite model)
                                .build();

                CustomObjectDetectorOptions customObjectDetectorOptions =
                        new CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                                .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE)
                                .enableMultipleObjects()
                                .enableClassification()
                                .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                                .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                                .build();

                ObjectDetector objectDetector =
                        ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);

                objectDetector
                        .process(image)
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail. Sad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //textView.setText("Fail. Sad!");
                                imageProxy.close();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> results) {

                                for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
                                    Rect box = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();


                                    for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                                        String text = label.getText();
                                        int index = label.getIndex();
                                        float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                        textView.setText(text);



                                }}
                                imageProxy.close();
                            }
                        });

            }
            //ImageAnalysis.Builder.fromConfig(new ImageAnalysisConfig).setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST);

        }

    }


    PreviewView prevView;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    TextView textView;

    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    private String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA"};
   /* @NonNull
    @Override
    public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
        return CameraXConfig.Builder.fromConfig(Camera2Config.defaultConfig())
                .setCameraExecutor(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
                .build();
    }
*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prevView = findViewById(R.id.viewFinder);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.scan_button);

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }

    }

    private void startCamera() {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindPreview(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                    // This should never be reached.
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));


    }

    void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(prevView.createSurfaceProvider());

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new YourAnalyzer());

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);


    }



    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        for(String permission: REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionsGranted()){
                startCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

}
```
````

Comment: 1. Labels are not showing up because it is up to you to draw them; 2. It actually is. This is the primary reason to return you a `List<DetectedObject>`. [Proof](https://imgur.com/a/sHsYuYP); 3. Not clear what do you mean by the third issue; **Ask one question at a time and be as specific as possible.** What have you tried to draw labels and boxes? Have you tried to put a number of different small objects in front of a camera to check whether it detects multiple objects? `label.getText()` will return you an empty string because object detector has no labels information.

Comment: How should I draw the labels? I tried using a textview, but apparently that doesn't work. I've tried putting multiple small objects in the camera, and it would recognize them (the textview would become blank), but when I move the camera away, the textview doesn't change back. Lastly, why doesn't objectdetector have any label information? Didn't it process the image?

Comment: `TextView` becomes blank because `label.getText()` returns an empty `String` but `label.getIndex()` returns you an integer - index of a label. You should have two files: model and a list of labels. Labels and model should be stored in `assets` folder. You can read lines of a text file at runtime into a `List<String>` and query label by index returned from `label.getIndex()`.

Comment: "why doesn't objectdetector have any label information?" - I'm not sure exactly why. Maybe `tflite` model does not have any label information. I do not have profound experience in ML. Checkout [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/ankitjamuar/android-firebase-mlkit). Maybe it will give you some answers or direct you towards them.

Comment: So I downloaded the starter model from the TensorFlow Lite guide on this page (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#starter_model). It contains both a tflite file and a label file as well, but when I run it, it fails to detect, giving me this error: (com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector.)

Comment: Your implementation is good for the image classification model. Object detection model requires a slightly different approach. Btw, [here is the drawing of rectangles](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java#L204) for object detection.

Comment: Hmm, what's missing in my approach? Does my program require something as complex as in that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. When adding a TensorFlow model to help with the object detection, apparently it has to contain metadata (so that that way, when you want to call "getLabels()" and its appropriate methods, it will actually return a label. Otherwise it will return nothing and cause errors apparently.
[image: MLKit screen showing metadata requirement]

This is the one I used that worked: mobilenet_v1_0.50_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite

Comment: How do you get the label from this model? I have the index of a detected object not sure how to get the label?

Comment: The model automatically comes with labels in its metadata. Everything else is in the last answer below that starts with "To answer your #3 question:"

Answer (score 0):

To answer your #3 question:

> Once it detects an object, the app won't "change" (i.e when I move the phone, to try to detect another object, nothing in the display changes.

I'm guessing this is caused by the fact that your `imageProxy().close` needs to be a part of an OnCompletedListener else it will cause various threading issues and possibly be leading to the blocking of any additional images from being processed that you mention.

i.e.:

Change this:

```java
objectDetector
    .process(image)
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail. Sad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //textView.setText("Fail. Sad!");
            imageProxy.close();
        }
    })
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> results) {

            for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
                Rect box = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();

                for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                    String text = label.getText();
                    int index = label.getIndex();
                    float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                    textView.setText(text);
            }}
            mediaImage.close();
            imageProxy.close();
        }
    });
```

to this:

```java
objectDetector
    .process(image)
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail. Sad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //textView.setText("Fail. Sad!");
            imageProxy.close();
        }
    })
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> results) {

            for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
                Rect box = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();

                for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                    String text = label.getText();
                    int index = label.getIndex();
                    float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                    textView.setText(text);
            }}
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Barcode>>() {  
        @Override  
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Barcode>> task) {   
            imageProxy.close();  
            }  
    });
```

Note I did not check the accuracy of your curly brace locations/levels, so ensure you have those correct as well.

I had similar issues, among others all related to this missing OnCompleteListener. See the original reasoning I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022377/2760299) and how this applies more specifically to the Task object created by your `objectDetector.process(image)`, or in my case `Task<List<Barcode>> result = scanner.process(image)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63242768/2760299) for details.

Comment: So it's weird. When I implement this, and try to debug/log it, I notice that my phone can detect an object successfully... but it can not return any labels at all. When I test it, I get out of bounds exceptions with the getLabels() return a size of 0. What can be causing this?

Comment: The default pretrained model doesn't have labels for all objects it detects, just some, so you have to add logic to handle a length 0 `result.object.getLabels()` . Point it at a chair or cabinet. It does well with "home goods" and "fashion". The [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/e949654bef09e97b237c7692349c52ee06e9fd9e/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/objectdetector/ObjectGraphic.java#L128-L137) uses a foreach loop to handle the zero length labels.

Comment: @topher271 So it appears that it is the model I used that is the problem then, correct? I just need to find a good pretrained model (or train one myself)? That's what I assume. If so, are there any you recommend? (BTW, was that sample app using Firebase MLKit or AutoML? It looks different than what I'm using. I'm using the current MLKit that doesn't require firebase.)

Comment: Actually yeah, the model was the issue. I needed one that came with it's own metadata (which includes labels). I'm not sure why certain labels don't come with metadata however.

Comment: It depends on the problem you are trying to solve. No model can classify EVERY detected object. A given model is trained on a given data set. You can see this as evidenced by switching between the "Object Detection" and "Custom Object Detection (Bird)" models in the [vision quickstart sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/e949654bef09e97b237c7692349c52ee06e9fd9e/android/vision-quickstart)

Comment: the first uses a more general model which is good for everyday objects but bad at classifying different kinds of birds, while the 2nd is trained on birds only, so your pen will be classified as a bird, but an actual bird will be classified more accurately than the general model.

Comment: So if you want a more accurate classifier for the particular set of objects you are hoping to recognize, you could either train your own, or try finding a better fit existing pretrained one. There are a bunch as detailed in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#tfhub).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221186/discussion-between-topher217-and-erick-adam).