# Why are images not being acquired by the analyze() method?

Tags: java, android-studio, machine-learning, android-camerax, google-mlkit

**Summary/TL;DR**: ML Object Detection application is unable to detect objects because images aren't being acquired by `analyze()` method.

---

---

## BACKGROUND

I'm currently working on a mobile application using CameraX and Google ML Kit written in Java. The purpose of the application is to detect objects with a real time camera preview. I implemented ML Kit using this guide aptly titled ["Detect and track objects with ML Kit on Android"](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/android#3.-process-the-image) (base model option) to detect objects in successive frames within the application.

However, upon running the application, it launches on my device and the camera preview continues to work but the application does not carry out its intended effect of actually detecting objects and displaying it on my screen. To attempt to resolve this, I had found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606320/mlkit-object-detection-is-not-detecting-objects) that very closely resembles this issue. To my dismay, the user had built their application using a custom model (tflite). This differs from mine as I am using the base model. According to my research, this uses the ML Kit's on-device's object detection. The code being applied is restricted to what is present within the aforementioned documentation. Since my IDE (Android Studio) does not display any errors within the syntax, I am unsure as to why any object detection does not appear to be present on my application. Displayed below is the necessary code that had been used:

## CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private class YourAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        @Override
        @ExperimentalGetImage
        public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
            Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                InputImage image =
                        InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                //Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                //...

                ObjectDetectorOptions options =
                        new ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder()
                                .setDetectorMode(ObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                                .enableClassification()  // Optional
                                .build();

                ObjectDetector objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(options);

                objectDetector.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> detectedObjects) {
                                        Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + detectedObjects.size());
                                        for (DetectedObject detectedObject : detectedObjects) {
                                            Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();
                                            Integer trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
                                            for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                                                String text = label.getText();
                                                if (PredefinedCategory.FOOD.equals(text)) { }
                                                int index = label.getIndex();
                                                if (PredefinedCategory.FOOD_INDEX == index) { }
                                                float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        imageProxy.close();
                                    }
                                }
                        )

                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.d("TAG", "onFailure" + e);
                                        imageProxy.close();

                                    }
                                }
                        );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {}
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

    }

    void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280,720))
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new YourAnalyzer());

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);
    }
}
```

## END OBJECTIVE

If any sort of visual example is required to understand what the intended effect should result in, Here it is included in the following image.

[image]

**UPDATE [April 11, 2021]:** After I attempted to debug by `Log.d(..)`ing the `OnSuccess` method in order to determine the return object list size, the AS console had printed  `D/TAG: onSuccess0` upwards of up to 30 times within a couple seconds of running the application. Would this mean that the application is not detecting any objects? This has bugged me since I had followed the documentation exactly.

**UPDATE [MAY 1, 2021]:** The line `DetectedObject[] results = new DetectedObject[0];` was deleted from the `onSuccess` method.

`for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results)` now uses "detectedObjects" instead of "results" to reflect code present within the documentation. However, `onSuccess` is still logging `D/TAG: onSuccess0`, which further increases questions on why the method isn't acquiring any data whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [this minimalized version of the Google ML Kit sample app](https://coderanch.com/p/3447191) provided courtesy of @Steven, I was able to resolve this issue by implementing a lambda expression and minimizing the code like so;

```
objectDetector.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(detectedObjects -> {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + detectedObjects.size());
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage()))
                        .addOnCompleteListener(result -> imageProxy.close());
```

Upon running the program after making this change, the application launched successfully and my logcat printed out `D/TAG: onSuccess1` signifying that an object has indeed been detected!

However, I do want to add that such a subtle difference in writing the code has me wondering what exactly the difference caused. If anybody could clear up why this code had worked as opposed to what I had posted in the OP, I would greatly appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606320/mlkit-object-detection-is-not-detecting-objects) you linked, you need to bind the analysis use case to make it work.

One tip to help debug this is that you can add some Log.d(..) in onSuccess to check the size of the returned object list and in onFailure to print out the exception.  Then when running, you could use adb logcat or the AS log tab to check the info to make sure things are running.

Another improvement you can make is that, you don't need to create a new object detector each frame. You can create one out side the analyze method and reuse it.

Comment: So I've attempted to bind the analysis use case exactly as how it was in the answer of the StackOverflow question that I linked, only to run and have it run and still not work. Would there be any reason as to why?

Also, how would I be able to `Log.d(..)` both `onSuccess` and `onFailure`? I've spent the last 2 days attempting to just this after reading your answer. I should add that I am fairly new to coding, and so any guidance would mean the world.

Comment: In your code, you already have the onSuccess and onFailure method implemented. You can just call Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess " + detectedObjects.size()); in the first line of the onSuccess method and Log.d("TAG", "onFailure " + e); in the first line of onFailure method.     
Here is the documentation about Log: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)
 
To view the log, open your terminal and run "adb logcat -s "TAG" when you run your app.  More about logcat: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: The `Log.d(..)` in `OnSuccess` prints out `D/TAG: onSuccess0` with `onFailure` printing nothing in the logcat. This means that no size of the returned object list was printed, correct? Which means that the ML Kit must not be detecting any objects.

Comment: Thanks for checking the log. This means there is no fatal error in the object detector.  Do you see a ton of these logs? If only a few or just one, it could be the image is not close() properly thus blocked.     In the setAnalyzer call, I saw you are using mainExecutor. Could you try something else, e.g. a singleThreadExectuor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().   Another thing you can verify is that whether the image you send in to the detector is correct by drawing it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't just a single one of these logs. In fact, it has printed the `D/TAG: onSuccess0` upwards of over 30 times within a couple seconds of running the application. This must mean that the image is `close()` properly, correct? As for using the mainExecutor, I've only resorted to it because of [this portion of the documentation when implementing CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) as well as the code to [this user's SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606320/mlkit-object-detection-is-not-detecting-objects) in refining my code.

Comment: I don't have too much more ideas based on the current available information.   Does the object detection in MLKit sample app work fine for you on your device? https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Comment: Is there any additional information I should add to supplement my question then? And yes, it has been quite a while since I've used the MLKit sample app but it did work just fine. My question was pertaining as to why I had followed the Google MLKit documentation and it did not work. Regardless, thank you so much for your help. I will be updating my post with the information that I had collected thanks to you!

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/741758/java/aren-images-acquired-analyze-method#3446951

Comment: @Steven I have posted a response on CodeRanch to your answer regarding some minor issues I had. Thank you for taking your time out and doing this!

Comment: @Steven just to clarify, `D/TAG: onSuccess1` does indicate that an object was detected, correct?

Comment: Yes. (as replied in coderanch.com/p/3447755)